# Macro for project list. need to copy and paste data from one sheet to the next based on the entry of a completion date

Tags: excel

I want to enter a completion date in row a on sheet "Master Project List" and have Excel copy that row and paste the data on a separate sheet named "completed projects".

How can I tell Excel to copy and then paste a row of data to a separate sheet based on the completion date listed in row a?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy rows in excel to sheets if condition is .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782875/copy-rows-in-excel-to-sheets-if-condition-is)

Answer (score 0):

Some questions for you:

Is this a macro that will copy the currently highlighted row to CompletedProjects, or does it need more smarts than that?  Do you want to compare both sheets and only copy data from MasterProjectList that hasn't been copied yet?

Depends on the answer to this question to the complexity of the macro. It sounds to me that MasterprojectList is a work in progress, whilst the CompletedProjects is not.

So, I am guessing that column A contains data only if the project is completed.
Column B contains project title or some other data always.

here's the macro:

```
Sub CompletedProjects()
   Dim MPL, CP
   Dim MPLRow, CPRow
   Dim blFound

   Set MPL = Sheets("master project list")
   Set CP = Sheets("completed projects")

   MPLRow = 2
   Do While MPL.Cells(MPLRow, 2) <> ""
      If MPL.Cells(MPLRow, 1) <> "" Then
         CPRow = 2
         blFound = False
         Do While CP.Cells(CPRow, 2) <> ""
            If CP.Cells(CPRow, 2) = MPL.Cells(MPLRow, 2) Then
               blFound = True
               Exit Do
            End If
            CPRow = CPRow + 1
         Loop
         If Not blFound Then
            'copy the MPL row to CP
            MPL.Rows(MPLRow).Copy Destination:=CP.Range("A" & CPRow)
         End If
      End If
      MPLRow = MPLRow + 1
   Loop

   Set MPL = Nothing
   Set CP = Nothing
End Sub
```

In essence, it will loop through and read every line in the Master project list until it finds an empty cell in Column B.

If it finds something in Column A, it will search for the same in the Completed Projects sheet.

If it cannot find the same, the macro will copy and paste the line at the bottom of the Completed projects Sheet.

If it does find the same, it ignores it